"Selected dimensions and metrics cannot be queried together." - UA API
After attempting to run this piece of code with Universal Analytics version 4, I encountered an error:
code :
def get_ua_report(analytics):
    """Fetches the report data from Google Analytics UA."""
    return analytics.reports().batchGet(
        body={
            'reportRequests': [
                {
                    'viewId': VIEW_ID,
                    'dateRanges': [{'startDate': config['UA_INITIAL_FETCH_FROM_DATE'], 'endDate': config['UA_FETCH_TO_DATE']}],
                    'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:users'}],
                    'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:date'}, {'name': 'ga:acquisitionSource'},{'name': 'ga:acquisitionCampaign'},{'name': 'ga:acquisitionMedium'},],
                    'pageSize': 10000
                }
            ]
        }
    ).execute()


Error occurred: <HttpError 400 when requesting
https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet?alt=json
returned "Selected dimensions and metrics cannot be queried
together.". Details: "Selected dimensions and metrics cannot be
queried together.">

I checked all documents and used Google's tool (https://ga-dev-tools.google/dimensions-metrics-explorer/). It confirmed that the metrics and dimensions are compatible. can anyone help me fix this issue?

Solution is to pick different dimensions and metrics.
The reason they are incompatible is that the data doesn't exist so you can't query them together
